# What Does it Mean to Reacquire A Lock (Wait(object, TimeSpan))?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I've been reading the documentation for [`Monitor.Wait(object, Timespan)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.wait#System_Threading_Monitor_Wait_System_Object_System_TimeSpan_),  and so I'm having a tough time understanding what it means for a lock to be reacquired. The documentation states:

> **Returns**
>
> *Boolean*
>
> *true* if the lock was reacquired before the specified time
>   elapsed; *false* if the lock was reacquired after the specified time
>   elapsed. *The method does not return until the lock is reacquired.*

I've made a little example and wanted to know if someone can explain using my example below. Where is the lock being reacquired, if at all, and by which thread?

```
     class Program
     {
        static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static int x = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(Write).Start();
            new Thread(Read).Start();
        }

        static void Read()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                while (x != 10)
                    if (!Monitor.Wait(_lock, 5000))
                        Console.WriteLine("Timeout!");
                Console.WriteLine($"{x} is 10!");
            }
        }

        static void Write()
        {
            while (x < 10)
            {
                x++;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }
        }
    }
```

In general, if someone can provide an example for when `Wait(Object, Timespan` will return true, false, and not return at all, I will give you the winning answer. Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the documentation is confusing you? Doesn't it say exactly when `Wait` returns true or false? Not returning at all means you have a dead lock. In your code, you are locking and then waiting for the lock inside the locked code. This makes no sense, since you are the one locking it

Comment: All of `DoWork` is done by thread `Me` so it will be trying to acquire the lock. In the `main` method, the main thread will be trying to acquire a lock in `lock (_lock)` .

Comment: @CodingYoshi So I deadlocked myself? Isn't the whole point of Wait that it holds the lock, and when llock has Pulse called on it, `Me` is released ?

Comment: Imagine you have 10 threads: 1 feeder and 9 eaters. The job of feeder is to enqueue items into a queue and the job of each eater is to dequeue the item and eat it. Now imagine an eater is ready to eat an item so it locks the queue. It checks and there is nothing to eat so what should it do?

Comment: It can release it and go and wait quietly until it's turn comes again or it can call `Wait` and release the queue so feeder can lock it and put something in it. When feeder puts an item in the queue, it will call pulse and that will eventually notify the waiting eater. After the temporary time elapsed, or a pulse is sent, the eater will check the queue again and voila it has an item and it will dequeue and eat it. So basically it is a mechanism for multiple threads to share a resource and depending on status of resource, lock or release it temporarily and then lock it again. Co-operation!!

Comment: A very important point to remember is that it is not threads that get released and locked. It is the resources. Think of threads like people and resources like items people use.

Comment: I want to use Wait(object, TimeSpan) to throw an exception if, after a long period of time where the feeder checks the queue, there is nothing in the queue. Is my code above (removing x = 0) not achieving that?

Comment: And no you didn't deadlock yourself because regardless of who gets a lock on `_lock` first, it will eventually release it. Then the next thread can get a lock on it. Deadlock would happen if one thread `t1` got a lock on `lock1` and while it has that lock it wants a lock on something else say `lock2` which is locked by another thread `t2` and it also is waiting for a lock on `lock1`. Then a deadlock will happen. *You let go first! No you! You first! No you first!*

Comment: @CodingYoshi That makes sense. Like:
`lock (lock1) { lock(lock2) {...} };`
`lock (lock2) { lock(lock1) {...} };`

But how can I best use the timeout to stop looking at an item if I know that after 60 minutes, if it's still empty, I want to throw an exception? (See my new edited example and let me know if it is correct usage)

Comment: If you want an exception to be thrown on timeout, then the solution is simple. Just replace the line `Console.WriteLine("Timeout!")` with `throw new TimeoutException()`.